# How to find and review all python scripts in a Blend file

Tags: python, scripting

If you download a Blender file that has python in it, there is a warning to enable that script or not. If you want to use the file with python enabled, it not clear how to check for malicious scripts.

1. Where are all possible locations for python scripts?
2. Are there any tools or utilities to simplify checking for malicious python scripts in a Blend file?

Comment: Can be registered *Text-Blocks* or *Animation Drivers* -> Text blocks are easy to find, either open up a *Text Editor* and click the dropdown list at the center of the header or use the console and type: `[t for t in D.texts]`. However, drivers are harder to find https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/security.html

Comment: Are there places beside the text editor and drivers where Python scripts can reside?

Comment: Since there is no other multi-line input field like the *Text Editor*, the answer is No. You can theoretically run the contents of a 3d text object, you have to call it from a text block though.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/how-to-prevent-malicious-code-execution-loading-blend-files  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/how-to-determine-whether-a-python-script-is-hostile